# Fetch POST via form action attribute

Tags: php, forms

I don't remember where I read this: Passing data via the form action attribute is safer than passing it via a href attribute. Safer in terms of validating the segment because it's $_POST and you can compare tokens for csrf protection when a form is submitted unlike a direct link. Is this true?

If suppose I have the following action in a form,

```
<form method="post" action="/edit/pictures/delete/2235/">
```

Can I get the URI segment `2235` via $_POST?

Edit: Please assume that there is a URL rewrite. `2235` is a variable value. I'm not asking how to retrieve `2235`, just if I can retrieve it via `$_POST`

Comment: What do you mean by safer - security-wise or reliability-wise? ... Re how to get the segment, you probably have URL rewriting enabled somewhere - you would have to post the rewrite rules

Comment: From an application security standpoint, data coming from POST or GET is irrelevant, they should be treating identically (i.e., not trusted). This generally applies for all user input. However, by defining your variables in the form action, they will be available through the GET array (not without some magic since you are using pretty urls).

Comment: Assume what url rewrite? Can you post your specific rules.

Comment: @Ben Lee, URL rewrite of `?some_id=2235` to `2235`

Comment: the answer to your question is 'sometimes', it depends on your rewrite rules. Please post your exact rewrite rules or we can't say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you POST a form to a php endpoint, $_POST only gets populated with data from the input elements. The request path is available in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. To get the id id out of the request path, you'll probably want to use a regular expression like this:

```
preg_match('/\/\d+\/?$/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
$matches[0] // Contains '2235'
```

Regarding your question about safety -- the answer is POST is absolutely no safer than GET. They are different HTTP verbs, and carry data in a slightly different way, but either way the data your app receives cannot be trusted. It's just as easy to spoof a POST request (like a form) as it is to spoof a GET request (like an anchor link).

Answer (score 3):

On your action page, explode `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

```
$parts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

foreach($parts as $slug)
{
    echo htmlspecialchars($slug);
}
```

You should be able to extract that ID.

Another approach is just to put it as a hidden HTML field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="2235" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use such URLs, you'll probably have some .htaccess that translates it to query parameters accessed from $_GET - try something like this [writing from my mind, needs testing]:

```
RewriteRule ^/edit/pictures/delete/(.+)$ ?module=pictures&action=delete&id=$1
```

If not, you can always access `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and extract necessary information from there.

Comment: You can't. Content in form action attribute is a GET request parameter, so all parameters contained are GET paameters.